# How to model censored and clustered data?

Tags: censoring

Mixed models can be used to handle clustered data.
TOPIT models can be used to handle censored data.

I am dealing with a dataset that are both censored and clustered.

is there any modeling techniques that are appropriate ?

Comment: Take a look at this link, below : https://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Tobit-Fixed-Effects-td3814771.html

Answer (score 0):

The analogue of mixed models for survival analysis are called **frailty** models.

There are packages in R to add frailty terms to both the Cox model and parametric survival models

It is also possible to model clustered censored data with marginal models and 'sandwich'-type standard error estimators.  The standard implementations of survival analysis in R and Stata (and probably other software) allow for these clustered standard error estimators.

Comment: the censored data I have are not survival ( time to event), I am talking about censored data with known upper bound.

Comment: an example : we have a measure of academic aptitude (scaled 200-800) which we want to model using reading and math test scores, as well as, the type of program the student is enrolled in (academic, general, or vocational). The problem here is that students who answer all questions on the academic aptitude test correctly receive a score of 800, even though it is likely that these students are not “truly” equal in aptitude. The same is true of students who answer all of the questions incorrectly. All such students would have a score of 200, although they may not all be of equal aptitude.